# Javascript location.search

Tags: javascript

How could I specifically get every of these query strings in

file:///K:/CKaing_C20_A01_Casino2/game.html?First+Name=Testfirst&Last+Name=Testlast&pnum=123-456-7890&postCode=A1A+1A1&startMoney=5000

For example, I want to get Testfirst, and then assign it to a variable so I can use it later on. Same thing with the others.

This is what I have so far to remove all the +, =

```
var formData = location.search;

formData = formData.substring(1, formData.length);

while (formData.indexOf("+") != -1) {
    formData = formData.replace("+", " ");
}

formData = unescape(formData);
var formArray = formData.split("&");
for (var i=0; i < formArray.length; ++i) {
    document.writeln(formArray[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var splitSearch = JSON.parse("{\""+(location.search.substr(1).replace(/\=/g,"\"\:\"").replace(/\&|(\/\?)/g,"\", \""))+"\"}")
```

I made that one for a webpage that uses a rare ("/?") separator too.

http://example.com/?a=0&b=bee/?c=third

First one will work for URLs like that

If you want it for a conventional location:

```
var splitSearch = JSON.parse("{\""+(location.search.substr(1).replace(/\=/g,"\"\:\"").replace(/\&/g,"\", \""))+"\"}")
```

Once splitSearch is defined you can get "pnum" string like this:

```
splitSearch.pnum
splitSearch["pnum"]
```

---

Another way to get it:

```
var splitSearch = JSON.parse("{\""+(location.search.substr(1).replace(/(\=)|(\&)|(\/\?)/g, function(k) {
 var rtn=k;
 if (k == "\=") rtn="\"\:\"";
 else if ((k == "\&") /*|| (k == "\/\?")*/) rtn="\",\"";
 return rtn;
})+"\"}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A mix of use of replace with regEx and the split function does the work.

```
var str = "file:///K:/CKaing_C20_A01_Casino2/game.html?
     First+Name=Testfirst&Last+Name=Testlast
     &pnum=123-456-7890&postCode=A1A+1A1&startMoney=5000";

var argStrIndex = str.indexOf("?");
var argStr = str.substring(argStrIndex+1);
var args = argStr.replace(/\+/g," ").split("&");

for (var i=0;i<args.length;i++){
     alert(args[i]);   
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7meAv/

Answer (score 0):

something like that :

```
var search = location.search
    .replace(/^\?/,'')
    .replace(/\+/g,' ')
    .split('&')
    .map(function(string){ 
        var split = string.split('=');
        var res={};
        res[split[0]]=split[1];
        return res;
});
```

should return

[{"First Name":"Testfirst"},{"Last Name":"Testlast"},{"pnum":"123-456-7890"},{"postCode":"A1A 1A1"},{"startMoney":"5000"}]"

You'd need to take care of url encoding though.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the two answers already given (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/russianator/GymEq/)

```
var url = 'file:///K:/CKaing_C20_A01_Casino2/game.html?First+Name=Testfirst&Last+Name=Testlast&pnum=123-456-7890&postCode=A1A+1A1&startMoney=5000';

queryObject = {};
url.substring(url.indexOf('?')+1)
 .replace(/\+/g,' ')
 .split('&')
 .forEach(function(item) {
    splitItem = item.split('=');
    queryObject[splitItem[0]] = splitItem[1];
 });
```

Returns an object like this:

```
{
  "First Name": "Testfirst",
  "Last Name": "Testlast",
  ...
}
```

Comment: I like turning things into an object where you can then in turn reference values via a key to get the corresponding value.